# Recursive Decryption of String with AES-256-cbc

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, aes, python-3.6

I am trying to decrypt an AES CBC string for the number of times it was decrypted.
I was successful in decrypting the first time.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

k = '57067125438768260656188878670043'
key = bytes(k, 'ascii')
i = '5706712543876826'
iv = bytes(i, 'ascii') 
dec = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
n = 2
cipher = 'dd3364461dbca39ddb5eb32e9f11b81f000acac9ce8b91369f8bf7e4a88787785a8cc498c85ea20370e68f0e7014e92a2b5aedd4c670ec172d7adb45dfa5a770b582e8ed255bb857d94afdfd6e579525f24890070f984b8862133eda9cbb118ba7880db125c32dea7e7c54bc77abfc02'


def unpad(s):
    return s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])]


def decrypt(cipherId):
    cipher = bytes.fromhex(cipherId)
    id = dec.decrypt(cipher)
    node_dec = unpad(id.decode('utf-8'))
    print (node_dec)
    return node_dec
```

that is the first stage of encryption, but I don't know how to set a loop to run the function again based on `n`. this cipher for example was encrypted twice, it might be three or four or more.

I created another function to decrypt the output of the decrypt function because the output gives a different codec.

```
def decrypt_again(cipherId):
    cipher = bytes.fromhex(cipherId)
    id =   dec.decrypt(cipher)
    node_dec = unpad(id.decode('ISO-8859-1'))
    print (node_dec)
    return node_dec
```

so I tried writing this loop

```
x = decrypt(cipher)
for i in range (n):
    y = decrypt_again(x)
```

but it only works for n = 1, if n is more than 1, it just keeps repeating y instead of parsing it again.

how can I go about it, please?

also if I re-run the function twice something happens to the string, I get `ó³*Ä'»g)X»#¾ú84-8089-be57330fcd45` instead of this `a214868d-f40b-4184-8089-be57330fcd45`, there seem to be a break in the codec

any reason why this is so?

Comment: Keep in mind that you're reusing the `dec` instance which has an internal state. If you have a challenge where the plaintext is encrypted multiple times with the same configuration then you must not reuse the AES instance and instead initialize it in every iteration with the same IV.

Comment: thanks. it worked, you can check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so guys I was able to solve the issue. here is the correct code that works top-notch.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

k = '57067125438768260656188878670043'
key = bytes(k, 'ascii')
i = '5706712543876826'
iv = bytes(i, 'ascii') 
n = 4
cipher = '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'


def unpad(s):
    return s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])]


def decrypt(cipherId):
    dec = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    cipher = bytes.fromhex(cipherId)
    id = dec.decrypt(cipher)
    node_dec = unpad(id.decode('ISO-8859-1'))
    return node_dec
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = decrypt(cipher)
    result = ""
    for i in range(n - 1):
        y = decrypt(x)
        x = y
        result = x

    print(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

every time it sets `y` to `decrypt_again(x)`,  `x` is still the same so you should add a line that sets `x` to `y` so it remembers the result of the previous iteration

```py
x = decrypt(cipher)
for i in range (n):
    y = decrypt_again(x)
    x = y
```

Comment: i tried this and got this error `ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 0`, also I updated my question, kindly look at the latter part.

Comment: don't know, sorry